# Uploading bytes using PySFTP with putfo

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

So I have a base64 string and wanting to decode into a file object and upload it with PySFTP. I'm getting an error:

> 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Is my decoding wrong here?

```
fileObj = base64.b64decode(attach["payload"])
srv.putfo(fileObj, filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Connection.putfo`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.putfo) takes a file-like object, not just "bytes":

```
fileObj = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(attach["payload"]))
```